# Can NSLocale's NSLocaleCountryCode key be directly mapped to a TLD?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

in my app i need to open a website with the corresponding TLD for that country. Lets say google.com, google.de, etc...

But i don't know which country codes the're specifically using in NSLocale's dict. Can i assume that the lowercase version of NSLocaleCountryCode can be appended as TLD?

Regards, Erik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Locales Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFLocales/Articles/CFLocaleConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002240-164446-BCIGEEJE):

> The region code is defined by ISO
>   3166-1

ISO 3166-1 is not equivalent to top level domains, at least not in all cases. For instance: .co.uk ≠ GB

On the other hand, there are only six or so exceptions. See the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_top-level_domain).

Comment: yes i know there are a few that can't be directly mapped but those could be handled separately as you said.